# WordPress - Including a variable in get_header does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, global-variables

For some reason whenever I try to put a variable in `get_header` in my custom page.php in WordPress, it doesn't recognise the value and resets to default.

Here's my code:

```
$header_choice = of_get_option( 'headerstyle', 'default' );
get_header( $header_choice );
```

of_get_option is a function from [Options Framework](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/)

This because I'm using multisite and it would be great if power users can change the header themselves per-site without having to dive into the code or having to ask us, the developers.

How can I use a variable in `get_header` so I can dynamically assign the value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running into a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. WordPress is including the header via it's own function `get_header()` and your template variables aren't available. You might find other folks recommending you just use `include('header.php')` but you **don't** want to do that either. (`get_header()` triggers other WordPress specific actions and it's important to keep it).

You have a couple of options, and one of them is my preference.

First, you can use the `global` keyword to hoist your variable into the global scope like so:

```
global $header_choice = of_get_option( 'headerstyle', 'default' );
get_header();
```

Then, *inside* `header.php` you would access it again using the global keyword like so:

```
// from inside header.php
global $header_choice;
if ($header_choice == 'some_option') {
    // do some work
}
```

But this pollutes the global scope a bit (and it can get to be disorganized, especially if you begin using globals in other pages and for other things).  So you can also scope your globals using the `$GLOBALS` array and nest all of your theme's globals into their own "namespaced" array like so:

Inside `functions.php` initialize your `$GLOBALS` variable

```
// from inside functions.php
$GLOBALS['THEME_NAME'] = array();
```

In your template file, initialize your theme options

```
$GLOBALS['THEME_NAME'] = array();
$GLOBALS['THEME_NAME']['header_choice'] = of_get_option( 'headerstyle', 'default' );
get_header();
```

In your `header.php` file you access it simply like so:

```
// from inside header.php
if ($GLOBALS['THEME_NAME']['header_choice'] == 'some_option') {
    // do some work
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be $GLOBALS